# Listing past events and all news items with certain category in Plone collection

Tags: plone

Using Plone 4.2, I would like to create a collection showing:

- all past events **and**
- all news items with a certain category
- Nice-to-have: ordered by start time (in case of event) or publication date (in case of news item). If this is not possible, then order just by publication date for all

How is this possible? As far as I see, I cannot have an "OR" combination of criteria but only "AND"

Background: I would like to have an "Events Archive". Problem is that older "events" are only available at this plone site in the form of *"This month' events overview"* kind of news items (because they actually stem from another CMS and where imported).

Comment: The best way would be to migrate the news-items to events, too, if I understood you correctly, because they are actually events, no? To avoid this time-consuming solution, maybe there is another sharp way to filter these 'news-items', f.e. by using collective.flag, and setting the extra-field to True for all events and all concerned News-Items or by putting all concerned items in one container and use location as criterion.

Answer (score 0):

ok, this does not work with vanilla plone collections. Only solution would be to install [AdvancedQuery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.AdvancedQuery) and create a custom template and catalog query.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the old-sytle-collections by activating them in the portal_types-tool.
They provide also an 'or'-operator, yet are deprecated.

Comment: I actually use the old collections (i.e. Topic not plone.app.collections), but I cannot find any way to configure anything 'or'-combined there.

Comment: Seems I didn't recall co, after having a closer look again, it appears the operators can only be applied to several selected values of one sinlge criterium (f.e. several keywords), not between several criterias, actually.